# Mysql. 1 table for all properties of all entities or 1 table per each entity

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Currently, I am dealing with database structure and I would like to get a piece of advice.

I have 2 objects: banner and ad.

For them I may create banner table and ad table, which will hold all the info about each entity. As main advantage I see that everything related to 1 entity is in this entity table.

On the other hand, I may some table like:
entity_properties.
It will hold value_id entity_id property value. The main advantage is that for entities I need only some basic fields, other fields can be put in this table.

But I am not sure which is the better practice and performance?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of normalization it is always better to have 1 table per 1 entity. Normalization is an aim or an approach to minimize redundancy and dependency in relational databases . In your case banner and ad are different entities. For now it seems that you can use them in same table. So "redundancy" is not the case. However, what if you want to add some additional fields later?

In addition code complexity and readability is another issue. For instance, when you add different types of object in same table you need to add an internal logic to differentiate them in your code. This means you have complex and probably less readable code.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the exact use of your system and the attributes/values you're trying to store.

As I see it, I think it would be good to save the important and required information in one table, your 'ad' table, and the rest in the 'ad_entities' table, with an ad_id, entity_name, entity_value, or something similar for your application.

This is a good performance choice since you'll be able to get all the information about the current Ad or all Ads using just one quite simple query, which your objects can easily figure out.

Comment: Yes, I'v tested a little bit. I think that it would be better to use 1 entity=1 table

Comment: I'm quite interested in your test results that decided you to conclude that, since if all these entities are required, you can probably just add them to the main Ad table, and if these entities aren't required/mandatory, it would be better not to have them in an individual table each.

Comment: My aim was to make database as simple as much. I thought what if I have only base entity tables, storing some main properties. And all other properties, of all other entities are stored in 'values' table. Where only entity_id, property and value are saved. entity_type_id might be also stored there. But the php code becomes a little bit more complex, so I decided to stick to the 1 entity=1table rule.